# How to specify Accept headers from rest_framework.test.Client?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set up an API endpoint to reply with HTML or JSON depending on the incoming request's Accept headers. I've got it working, testing through curl:

```
> curl --no-proxy localhost -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8000/feedback/
{"message":"feedback Hello, world!"}

> curl --no-proxy localhost -H "Accept: text/html" -X GET http://localhost:8000/feedback/
<html><body>
<h1>Root</h1>
<h2>feedback Hello, world!</h2>
</body></html>
```

I can't figure out how to use the APITestCase().self.client to specify what content should be accepted, though.

My view looks like

```
class Root(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,JSONRenderer)
    template_name="feedback/root.html"
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        data={"message": "feedback Hello, world!"}
        return Response(data)
```

and my test code looks like

```
class RootTests(APITestCase):
    def test_can_get_json(self):
        response = self.client.get('/feedback/',format='json',Accept='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.accepted_media_type,'application/json')
        js=response.json()
        self.assertIn('message', js)
        self.assertEqual(js['message'],'feedback Hello, world!')
```

which dies on the test for response.accepted_media_type. What's the right way to do this? All I can find says that the format argument should be sufficient.

Comment: What is `Accept='application/json'` for? What happens when you remove it?

Comment: Try this https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/850/

Comment: @DušanMaďar I was hoping that it would get passed into the underlying Request as a header. The test fails with and without it, and also with and without a "headers={'accept':'application/json'}" parameter.

Comment: @cakins check your settings according to https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#configuration

Comment: @Ken4scholars phrasing it as self.client.get('/feedback/', HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json') works nicely, I must have stared at the docs about that 'extra' parameter five times. Write it so I can accept.

Comment: @cakins Great. I'm glad to know it helped. I have posted it as an answer. You can accept and upvote

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As was rightfully stated [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/850/), the docs don't seem to say much about how to add headers to the request using the test client. However, the `extra` parameter can be used for that but the trick is that you have to write it the exact way the http  header looks. So you should do this:

```
self.client.get('/feedback/', HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json')
```